# Add support for various accents in Directline speech for Azure chat bot

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition, direct-line-botframework

We are working on a requirement where we need to support various accents for azure chat bot. Currently we have Directline speech enabled for the speech as below.

```js
(async function () {
    var speechServicesTokenRes = await fetch(
       'https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken',
        {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
               'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '***************'
           }
        });

    if (speechServicesTokenRes.status === 200) {
        authorizationToken = await speechServicesTokenRes.text();

        var webSpeechPonyfillFactory = await window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
            authorizationToken: authorizationToken,
            region: 'eastus'
        });
        window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
            directLine: createDirectLine({
                secret: '********************'
            }),

            webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
        }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    }
})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Can anyone guide me if there is any way to customize Directline speech for accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Direct Line Speech does not support accents. The full list of supported languages, including regional variations (for example Spanish (Honduras) vs Spanish (Panama)) can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#text-to-speech).

Direct Line Speech does support [SSML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp) (Speech Synthesis Markup Language) which has a rich set of associated features. Some options that *may* help you are:

- Adjusting speaking style to represent mood
- Adding / removing breaks or pauses
- Using phonemes to adjust pronunciation
- Using custom lexicons to adjust pronunciation
- Adjusting prosody (i.e., pitch, rate, valume, etc.)

One last option is to create a [custom neural voice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-neural-voice) which

> lets you create a one-of-a-kind customized synthetic voice for your applications.

In this case, you would provide audio and/or text samples in order to train the voice for use in customizing it.

Hope of help!